# Java Web Start bundled with JRE 8

Tags: java

I have checked and found that for Java 7, following holds true

Java Web Start version 1.7.0 is included in the Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 7 JDK

I got the above from oracle docs.
 But the same I am not able to find for Java 8.Is there any doc on oracle or is there any way to check the version of java web start.

Thanks
Amanjot Singh